# How to make Kaspersky trust programs developed with an IDE (e.g.-NetBeans, Eclipse, etc)

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I have searched here, Kaspersky Forums, and Googled but can't get a clear answer.

I am developing a program in NetBeans which means I recompile/relink every few minutes. Kaspersky continually interrupts the test runs so that I can choose to trust the application.

So, how do I get Kaspersky to trust applications I develop with an IDE? Particularly, in the Settings > Application Control > Manage applications section, is there something I have to set for NetBeans? or is there something I have to set for the exe of the developed program?

Comment: Normally antivirus software allow to discriminate paths from realtime analysis. I think Kaspersky allows you to do the same thing. But antivirus are antivirus, they are above the user.

Comment: Turrican, I think it does too. Do you know how?

Comment: Of course, here is the explanation : https://support.kaspersky.com/us/11386#block2

Comment: Thank you. We'll see if it works. :)

Comment: And it works beautifully. Thank you, Turrican.

Comment: No problem, can you make my answer a valid one? Is important for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally antivirus software allow to discriminate paths from realtime analysis. I think Kaspersky allows you to do the same thing. But antivirus are antivirus, they are above the user.

Here https://support.kaspersky.com/us/11386#block2 you can find the explanation.

Comment: Very useful answer. Just a remark: if the page linked is removed or moved... it would be better to explain which configuration need to be changed. Again very useful for removing the annoying security popups.